# why i get same values inside hash table?

Tags: c, hash, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I created hash table to insert my values . But when I insert more than one value I got same values inside all fields . my code is here :

create a structure for both user and hashtable

```
 struct UserNode
    {
    char *username;
    char *password;
    };

    struct HashTable
    {
        int size;
        struct UserNode *table;
    };
```

// initialize the hash table as NULL

```
      struct HashTable* initializeTable(int size)
       {

        struct HashTable *htable;
        int i = 0;
        if (size < MIN_TABLE_SIZE)
        {
                printf("Table Size Too Small\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        htable = malloc(sizeof(struct HashTable));

        if (htable == NULL)
        {
                printf("Out of Space\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        htable->size = size;

        htable->table = malloc(size * sizeof(struct UserNode));

        if (htable->table == NULL)
        {
                printf("Table Size Too Small\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < htable->size; i++)
        {
                htable->table[i].username= malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
                htable->table[i].password = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
                htable->table[i].username=NULL;
                htable->table[i].password=NULL;
        }

        printf("Hsh table sucessfully created\n");
        return htable;

       }
```

insert each user name to hash table

```
      int Insert(char *key,char *password,struct HashTable *htable)
     {
      int pos = 0;

      pos = Find(key,htable);
      printf("the value of key : %d\n",pos);
      if ((htable)->table[pos].username == NULL)
      {
        (htable)->table[pos].username,key ;
        (htable)->table[pos].password = password;
      }

      else
      {
                printf("Duplicate element ..\n");
      }
        return 0;
    }
```

This function to display the hash table

```
    void Retrieve(struct HashTable *htable)
     {

        int i=0;

     for (i = 0; i < htable->size; i++)
     {
        if (htable->table[i].username == NULL)

            printf("Position: %d \tusername : NULL\tpassword: NULL\n",i + 1);

        else

            printf("Position: %d \t username: %s\tpassword: %s\n",i + 1,htable->table[i].username,htable->table[i].password);

    }
    }
```

and I am calling these function from main function as :

............main codes............
     ...............................
     case 1:

```
    printf("Enter size of the Hash Table:\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    htable = initializeTable(size);

   break;
   case 2:

    if (i > htable->size)

    {
        printf("Table is Full, Rehash the table\n");

        continue;
    }
         printf("Enter the username:\n");
         scanf("%s",&username);
         printf("Ebter the password:\n");
         scanf("%s",&password);
         Insert(username,password,htable);
         i++;

    break;


 case 3:
        printf("Display\n");
        Retrieve(htable);

    break;
```

But when I insert more username and password inside structures via insert function , I got same values in both fields . that is the new one is overwrite the previous one and display both value as new username . why ? an problem on my code ?

Comment: Seems like a simple typo in the line `(htable)->table[pos].username,key ;`...

Comment: You allocate memory for `username` and `password` and then immediately set both to `NULL`. The allocated memory will be lost. Both fields should initially be `NULL`.

Comment: got segmentation fault when use strcpy( ) ,that's why I use (htable)->table[pos].username = key;

Comment: then how I make my character string is NULL for beginning ?

Comment: Because you just assign the pointers, all nodes will have the same `username` and `password` values. These fields held different data during input, but at the end, they just contain the last input set. As said, use `strcpy`, best in conjunction with `malloc`. (The function `strdup`, if your system has it, does both in one go.)

Comment: Well, you've done that already: `htable->table[i].username=NULL`. But You shoudn't allocate first. `NULL` is a special value that means: Nothing is being pointed to. It is a handy representation for: this slot is still free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Insert()`,

```
 if ((htable)->table[pos].username == NULL)
  {
    (htable)->table[pos].username,key ;
    (htable)->table[pos].password = password;
```

The `(htable)->table[pos].username,key;` line just did nothing. Also, strings should be copied through `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`, not through pointer assignment.

So it should be:

```
if (htable->table[pos].username == NULL)
{
    htable->table[pos].username = malloc(strlen(key) + 1);
    strcpy(htable->table[pos].username, key);
    htable->table[pos].password = malloc(strlen(password) + 1);
    strcpy(htable->table[pos].password, password);
}
```

Comment: mistake  (htable)->table[pos].username = key ;  ,but when I use strcpy I got segmentation fault .

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You have the code:

   ```
   htable->table[i].username= malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
   htable->table[i].password = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
   htable->table[i].username=NULL;
   htable->table[i].password=NULL;
   ```

   First you allocate memory, then you immediately overwrite the pointers with `NULL` making you loose the memory you just allocated, leading to a leak and possible [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and probable crashes) if you use the pointers without checking for `NULL`.
2. If you are going to allocate fixed sizes for the `username` and `password` members of the `UserNode` structure, why not make them arrays? Like

   ```
   struct UserNode
   {
       char username[20];
       char password[20];
   };
   ```

   This will, incidentally, also solve the first problem since you no longer need to allocate memory. It will also lessen memory fragmentation.